# Solution of differential equation $y' + c_1 y^2= c_2 e^{-c_2 x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am curious about the solution of the 1st order ODE
$$y' + c_1 y^2= c_2 e^{-c_2 x}$$
where $c_1, c_2$ are constants. WolframAlpha gives a complicated solution

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%28x%29%2Bc_1+y%28x%29%5E2%3D+c_2+e%5E%7B-c_2+x%7D

involving modified Bessel function, but I cannot see how it is derived.
Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y' = - c_1 y^2+ c_2 e^{-c_2 x}$$
This is a Riccati ODE. The usual way to solve it in the present case is the change of function :
$$y(x)=\frac{u'(x)}{c_1u(x)}$$
which transforms the non-linear ODE into a linear ODE :
$$u''-c_1c_2e^{-c_2x}u=0$$
Then the change of variable 
$$X=e^{-c_2x/2}$$
transforms it into an ODE of Bessel kind (Generalized Bessel). To solve it see Eqs.(6-7) in https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselDifferentialEquation.html